# Invalid Reference while making a group aggregation after projection

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

This example aggregation will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` Invalid reference 'role'!

We got this problem every time after renaming a field after a projection stage.

```
    final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(

            // We only like to have the "company" and "empolyee.role" renamed to "role"
            project("company")
                    .and("employee.role").as("role"),

            // Group by the **renamed** "role"
            group("role").count().as("count"), // this will fail because "role" is an invalid reference.
            limit(2)
            );

    return aggregation;
```

The JSON we are working on looks like this:

```
{
    // some fields
    company : {
          // some fields
    }

    employee : {
           role : {
                    // some fields
           }

    } 
}
```

**Thoughts:**

[Here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/130522-spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-framework-implementation-exceptions) Oliver said

> It's important to understand that you define aggregations in terms of type properties, not document field names.

Is that the reason why we get the exception? If so, how to use the nice aggegration api spring data offers.

**Update:**:

This is the Stacktrace i get with version 1.5.0.M1:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'role'!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation.toDBObject(GroupOperation.java:292)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.toDbObject(Aggregation.java:247)
    at com.xxx.report.adapter.AggrigateByTopic.aggrigateBy(AggrigateByTopic.java:38)
    at com.xxx.report.adapter.AggrigateByTopicTest.shouldAggrigate(AggrigateByTopicTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Which version are you using, what's the exact stack trace you're getting?

Comment: I've added the Stacktrace with 1.5.0.M1. (with older versions it is the same)

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the implementation "does not like" the type of field aliasing that you are doing here, but in the strictest interpretation, what you are doing does not make much sense.

Your statement should be something like:

```
    final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
          group("employee.role").count().as("count"),
          sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"count"),
          limit(2)
    );

    System.out.println(aggregation);
```

Which produces the pipeline as:

```
{ 
    "aggregate" : "__collection__", 
    "pipeline" : [ 
        { "$group" : { 
            "_id" : "$employee.role", 
            "count" : { "$sum" : 1}
        }}, 
        { "$sort" : { "count" : -1} },
        { "$limit" : 2}
    ]
}
```

The point being that your **`$project`** usage here isn't really doing anything other than selecting one field that you do not use later, and creating an alias for another field that you don't really use anyway as it just becomes the `_id` field for your grouping. Also note the use of **`$sort`** as it doesn't really make much sense to **`$limit`** unless you have things in an expected order, and **`$group`** does not do that by itself.

As for explaining the "properties" concept, which I am not really a fan of, then you might consider the following code:

```
    final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
          group("country","employee.role").count().as("count"),
          group("employee.role","count").count().as("totalCount"),
          sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"totalCount"),
          limit(2)
    );

    System.out.println(aggregation);
```

Then the pipeline that is constructed would look like this:

```
{ 
    "aggregate" : "__collection__", 
    "pipeline" : [ 
        { "$group" : { 
            "_id" : { 
                "country" : "$country" , 
                "role" : "$employee.role"
            },
            "count" : { "$sum" : 1}
        }}, 
        { "$group" : { 
            "_id" : { 
                "role" : "$_id.employee.role" ,
                "count" : "$count"
            }, 
            "totalCount" : { "$sum" : 1}
        }}, 
        { "$sort" : { "totalCount" : -1} }, 
        { "$limit" : 2 }
    ]
}
```

So while that will run through to the output dump as shown without an exception, there is still a problem in the pipeline produced. While the first **`$group`** statement compacts an alias for the sub-document field, and all if fine at this point, it is the second **`$group`** stage that introduces a problem.

The builder methods are just "not happy" unless you refer to that field by the full "employee.role" notation as property of the original document. And though it does work out that this will now be part of the `_id` field from the previous stage, it completely forgets that the field was aliased.

For my two cents, that is the wrong behavior and a strong reason why I am not a big fan of the builders.

So you can use them, but I think the design is not entirely there yet and has some flaws. Again, for my money it seems safer and more flexible to just work with `DBObject` types to construct the pipeline and be done with it. At least you know you always get exactly what you mean.

Comment: Yes, u are right. I do an "useless" projection in this example. I haven't saw that at the time writing the question. Anyway, the key thing tried to point out is, that **after** an projection on types, i'm not able to use the projected "field" in an other group stage.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Yep. And the key thing I am trying to point out is that there are problems with this in the current API, so use the DBObject construction form instead. There also was the point that if you constructed your statements differently then the API as it stands works. Either way, sure looks like a definitive answer to me.